# In Linux, with a series of supposedly sequentially named files, how can I do a check to verify all files are really there?

Tags: linux, grep, find

I currently have folders of 1000 files (supposedly) with the following names in a directory in Linux:

```
Simulation.Run.1.rds
Simulation.Run.2.rds
Simulation.Run.3.rds
...
Simulation.Run.999.rds
Simulation.Run.1000.rds
```

Sometimes, the software generating these files tends to skip some, so I may be missing, for example, `Simulation.Run.900.rds`. I am wondering if there is a simple to use command to verify that all 1000 files are there and to have the command possibly tell me which files might be missing, if any at all. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: here's an idea: use brace expansion to create all 1000 names and put it in a file.. save results of `ls -v` to a file and use diff on these two files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash you can check if files exist:

```
for((i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do name="Simulation.Run.${i}.rds"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && echo "missing $name"; done
```

Output (e.g.):

```
missing Simulation.Run.900.rds
missing Simulation.Run.901.rds
```

See: `help test`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other ideas, just for fun:

---

Simplest method:

```
ls Sim* | wc -l
```

This just counts the number of files present.

---

With **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel '[ -e Simulation.Run.{}.rds ] || echo {}' ::: {1..1000}
```

This generates a `test` statement for each expected file and echoes its number if it doesn't exist.

---

With `diff`:

```
diff <(printf "Simulation.Run.%d.rds\n" $(seq 1000) | sort) <(ls Sim* | sort)
```

This generates a pseudo-file containing the names of the files expected and another pseudo-file with the names of the files actually present and passes the two to `diff`.

---

With `diff` and `grep`:

```
seq 1000 | diff - <(ls Sim* | grep -Eo "\d+" | sort -n)
```

This generates a list of the expected numbers in the filenames and sends it to `diff` to compare with a list of the number parts extracted from the filenames that are actually present in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        seqNr = ARGV[i]
        gsub(/Simulation\.Run\.|\.rds/,"",seqNr)
        if ( seqNr != (prevSeqNr+1) ) {
            printf "File %s does not immediately follow %s\n", ARGV[i], ARGV[i-1] | "cat>&2"
        }
        prevSeqNr = seqNr
    }
    exit
}
' Simulation.Run.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just the basic commands :

```
$ for I in {1..1000} ; do ls "Simulation.Run.$I.rds" ; done | grep 'No such file'
```